# Reduce Standard Deviation of Binomial Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

The std of a discrete binomial distribution is $$\text{std}=\sqrt{nr(1-r)}$$ where $r$ is the probability of success on a given trial and $n$ is the total number of trials.

Based on the way I understand the formula, to reduce the std of a binomial distribution by half, the total number of trials must be reduced by fourth.

But I think I am probably wrong because:

1. Reducing the number of trials modify the original distribution because the number of trials is one of the two parameters in the binomial distribution. What I am looking for is a change in the number of trials so that the **same** distribution has std reduced by half.
2. Intuitively, the number of trials must be increased to lower std.

So my question is: What change must be made in the number of trials to reduce the std of the binomial distribution by half?

Comment: The formula $\sqrt{nr(1-r)}$ is for the standard deviation of the **sum** of $n$ i.i.d. binomial variables. This gets larger as $n$ does. The formula for the standard deviation of the **mean** of $n$ i.i.d. binomial variables is $\sqrt{r(1-r)/n}$. This gets smaller as $n$ gets larger.

Comment: Could you please explain a little more? What do you mean by std of the sum and of the mean?

Comment: Given $n$ random variables $x_1\ldots x_n$, the standard deviation of the sum is the standard deviation of $\sum\limits_{k=1}^nx_n$ and the standard deviation of the mean is the standard deviation of $\frac1n\sum\limits_{k=1}^nx_n$.

Comment: I am not sure you are correct on that. I just checked my sources very carefully and the std of the mean that you provided is actually the std of the proportion of successes in n trials: $\sqrt{r(1-r)/n}=std(X/n)$

Comment: And what is the difference between those?

Comment: ok I think I understand what you are saying. You are correct about it. My notation here is that X is the number of successes, not the individual one. And I am asking about the std of the sum.

Comment: I also had the same question. Here's what I found. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2147821/why-is-the-sd-of-a-larger-set-in-a-binomial-distribution-smaller